# How to use ng-blur on md-autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I want to use blur event on md-autocomplete but both ng-blur and md-blur not working.

```js
$scope.unFocus = function () {
            alert('Hello!');
        }
```

```html
<md-autocomplete md-no-cache="false" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text-change="searchLocation(searchText)"
                    md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in searchResult" md-item-text="item.address"
                    md-selected-item-change="changeLocation(item)" md-min-length="0" md-floating-label="Your Address" ng-blur="unFocus()">
            <md-item-template>
                <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.address}}</span>
            </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found>
                <i>Not Found {{searchText}}</i>
            </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Please provide some code it will help better to understand whts going wrong in your prgm ...man..

Comment: Does `UserLocation == null` ?

Comment: This is an issue with md-autocomplete . https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3906

Answer (score 3):

**ngBlur** and **ngFocus** will start working from **1.1.1** version of Angular Material